# What is the difference between State and StateObject in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

It seems to me like they are alternatives but I can't seem to find pros/cons of one over the other. Any help is much appreciated!

I looked on HackingWithSwift and the apple forums, but am still not sure

Comment: Biggest (but not only difference): `@StateObject` is for use with an `ObservableObject`. `@State` is generally used with value types (although not exclusively).

Comment: There are more differences listed here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject

Comment: `@StateObject` is for when you need a reference type for your view state and that's not very often now that we have `.task`

Answer (score 2):

`@State` is a source of truth that updates the `body` when the value changes, used mostly with value types.

`@StateObject` is a source of truth for `ObservableObject`s it is also the only safe way of initializing `ObservableObject`s in a `View`.

Pros and Cons are mostly opinion based so out of scope for SO. That being said...

`State` is used per Apple documentation for "managing interface state" and observable objects are for managing "managing model data".

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

It is generally considered best practice to use value types with SwiftUI. But this isn't always possible such as when dealing with delegates that require `NSObject` or when dealing with `actor`s.